# `aws lambda create-function` and continues to the next command

Tags: bash, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I want to create lambda and check if it succeeded. if it succeeds, run then next command.

```sh
aws lambda create-function --function-name "${function_name}" \
    --zip-file fileb://function.zip --handler index.handler --runtime nodejs12.x \
    --role=r1
return_code=$?
(( return_code != 0 )) && exit 1
  
aws lambda invoke --function-name "${function_name}" out \
    --log-type Tail \
    --query 'LogResult' --output text | base64 -d
```

When running `create-function`, it stuck.

```
    "RevisionId": "dbb34210-7ad7-4096-b5ff-878a4c0d57a3",
    "State": "Active",
    "LastUpdateStatus": "Successful",
    "PackageType": "Zip"
}
(END)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create and use a pipe to wait for the result.But it will discord

```sh
aws lambda create-function --function-name "${function_name}" \
    --zip-file fileb://function.zip --handler index.handler --runtime nodejs12.x \
    --role=r1 | cat
```

2. use `get-function` instead of `return_code=$?`

```sh
function is_exist() {
  aws lambda get-function \
    --function-name ${function_name} >/dev/null 2>&1
  return $?
}
return_code=$(is_exist)
```

or

```
return_code="${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
```